# Last item click null pointer excepction

Tags: android, listview, nullpointerexception

```
listView=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);

listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View viewItem, int position, long arg3) {
    if(!itemClicked)
    {

        viewItem = parent.getChildAt(position);
        ((Button)viewItem.findViewById(R.id.gov)).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        ((Button)viewItem.findViewById(R.id.re)).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        viewItem.invalidate();
        itemClicked=true;
        clickedItemPos=position;
        TextView text = (TextView)viewItem.findViewById(R.id.item);
        ime = text.getText();
    }
    else
    {
        viewItem=parent.getChildAt(clickedItemPos);
        ((Button)viewItem.findViewById(R.id.go)).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        ((Button)viewItem.findViewById(R.id.re)).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

    viewItem = parent.getChildAt(position);
    ((Button)viewItem.findViewById(R.id.go)).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    ((Button)viewItem.findViewById(R.id.re)).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    viewItem.invalidate();
    clickedItemPos=position;
    TextView text = (TextView)viewItem.findViewById(R.id.item);
    ime = text.getText();
    }
    final int[] coordAndCat = FavoriteCoord(ime.toString());
```

Nullpointer exception happens when I have more elements and when you scroll and click the last item on the listview. How to workaround this?

Note: I'm trying to display 2 buttons in every item that is being clicked. This code works for all clicks on items besides the last one (if there are many elements in the list and you need to scroll)

Comment: What do you mean with "when i have more elements"?

Comment: Whenever you talk about an exception show a stacktrace as well as your code.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/6baVGa4Q here is the logcat

@alfa64 If the number of elements is greater than the possible visible items, by that I mean when I have more elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`clickedItemPos` isn't defined after `else` unless `clickedItemPos=position` has been called earlier. What line does the error happen on?

Comment: if(!itemClicked)
 {
  
  viewItem = parent.getChildAt(position);
  --->((Button)viewItem.findViewById(R.id.gotherefav)).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);   <----- this line is errorous.

I use clickedItemPos for storing position of previously clicked item, so I can hide the buttons if previously any of the items was clicked (buttons already shown)

Answer (score 0):

```
 listView=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);

    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View viewItem, int position, long arg3) {
        if(!itemClicked)
        {

            viewItem = parent.getChildAt(position);

//start >> This might be where your problem is (R.id.gov)
            ((Button)viewItem.findViewById(R.id.gov)).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
//end <<

            ((Button)viewItem.findViewById(R.id.re)).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            viewItem.invalidate();
            itemClicked=true;
            clickedItemPos=position;
            TextView text = (TextView)viewItem.findViewById(R.id.item);
            ime = text.getText();
        }
        else
        {
            viewItem=parent.getChildAt(clickedItemPos);
            ((Button)viewItem.findViewById(R.id.go)).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            ((Button)viewItem.findViewById(R.id.re)).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

        viewItem = parent.getChildAt(position);
        ((Button)viewItem.findViewById(R.id.go)).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        ((Button)viewItem.findViewById(R.id.re)).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        viewItem.invalidate();
        clickedItemPos=position;
        TextView text = (TextView)viewItem.findViewById(R.id.item);
        ime = text.getText();
        }
        final int[] coordAndCat = FavoriteCoord(ime.toString());
```

I think you said R.id.gov instead of R.id.go unless R.id.gov is truly an id you have. That is the only thing I saw 'wrong', please show a stacktrace for the error next time, it would help in debugging =)

**EDIT**
is clickedItemPos initialized somewhere else? because if it isn't this line: `viewItem=parent.getChildAt(clickedItemPos);` in your else statement would probably be null if nothing was selected before. I understand you want to use this in order to check for previously clicked items, but if nothing was clicked before, this will never get set to a value and therefore be null try doing this in that else statement to avoid the possible null variable:

```
else
{
    if(clickedItemPos != null){ //only add this if there was a previous clicked item
       viewItem=parent.getChildAt(clickedItemPos);
       ((Button)viewItem.findViewById(R.id.go)).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
       ((Button)viewItem.findViewById(R.id.re)).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

       viewItem = parent.getChildAt(position);
       ((Button)viewItem.findViewById(R.id.go)).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
       ((Button)viewItem.findViewById(R.id.re)).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
       viewItem.invalidate();
       clickedItemPos=position;
       TextView text = (TextView)viewItem.findViewById(R.id.item);
       ime = text.getText();
    }else{
       viewItem = parent.getChildAt(position);
       ((Button)viewItem.findViewById(R.id.go)).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
       ((Button)viewItem.findViewById(R.id.re)).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
       viewItem.invalidate();
       clickedItemPos=position;
       TextView text = (TextView)viewItem.findViewById(R.id.item);
       ime = text.getText();
    }
```

}

hopefully that will fix it. In your stack trace it says line 91 in your class is the line causing the error, what variable is located on that line? that is usually a good indicator of what variable is causing the null pointer, but since we don't know the line numbers for your code it is hard to guess where the issue is.

Yes there is repeated code in that solution but you could always make a method to put the repeated code in and call that instead if you want.

Good Luck, hope this helps.

Comment: Fixed that, problem still occurs.